# WSDL complex CVC error

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have the following wsdl code for my web applicaiton:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns:tns="http://www.ebi.ac.uk/webservices/whatizit/ws"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    targetNamespace="http://www.ebi.ac.uk/webservices/whatizit/ws" name="whatizit">

    <types>
        <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            targetNamespace="http://www.ebi.ac.uk/webservices/whatizit/ws"
            version="1.0">

            <xs:element xmlns:ns1="http://www.ebi.ac.uk/webservices/whatizit/ws"
                type="ns1:search" name="search" />
            <xs:complexType name="search">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" name="pipelineName" />
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" name="query" />
                    <xs:element name="limit">
                        <xs:simpleType>
                            <xs:restriction base="xs:int">
                                <xs:minInclusive value="0" />
                                <xs:maxExclusive value="10000" />
                            </xs:restriction>
                        </xs:simpleType>
                    </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>

            <xs:element xmlns:ns2="http://www.ebi.ac.uk/webservices/whatizit/ws"
                type="ns2:searchResponse" name="searchResponse" />
            <xs:complexType name="searchResponse">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" name="return" />
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>

            <xs:element xmlns:ns3="http://www.ebi.ac.uk/webservices/whatizit/ws"
                type="ns3:WhatizitException" name="WhatizitException" />
            <xs:complexType name="WhatizitException">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" name="message" />
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>

            <xs:element xmlns:ns4="http://www.ebi.ac.uk/webservices/whatizit/ws"
                type="ns4:contact" name="contact" />
            <xs:complexType name="contact">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" name="pipelineName" />
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" name="text" />
                    <xs:element type="xs:boolean" name="convertToHtml" />
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>

            <xs:element xmlns:ns5="http://www.ebi.ac.uk/webservices/whatizit/ws"
                type="ns5:contactResponse" name="contactResponse" />
            <xs:complexType name="contactResponse">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" name="return" />
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>

            <xs:element xmlns:ns6="http://www.ebi.ac.uk/webservices/whatizit/ws"
                type="ns6:queryPmid" name="queryPmid" />
            <xs:complexType name="queryPmid">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" name="pipelineName" />
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" name="pmid" />
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>

            <xs:element xmlns:ns7="http://www.ebi.ac.uk/webservices/whatizit/ws"
                type="ns7:queryPmidResponse" name="queryPmidResponse" />
            <xs:complexType name="queryPmidResponse">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" name="return" />
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>

            <xs:element xmlns:ns8="http://www.ebi.ac.uk/webservices/whatizit/ws"
                type="ns8:getPipelinesStatus" name="getPipelinesStatus" />
            <xs:complexType name="getPipelinesStatus" />

            <xs:element xmlns:ns9="http://www.ebi.ac.uk/webservices/whatizit/ws"
                type="ns9:getPipelinesStatusResponse" name="getPipelinesStatusResponse" />
            <xs:complexType name="getPipelinesStatusResponse">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element xmlns:ns10="http://www.ebi.ac.uk/webservices/whatizit/ws"
                        type="ns10:selectItem" minOccurs="0" name="return" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>

            <xs:complexType name="selectItem">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" name="description" />
                    <xs:element type="xs:boolean" name="disabled" />
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" name="label" />
                    <xs:element type="xs:anyType" minOccurs="0" name="value" />
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:schema>
    </types>


    <message name="contact">
        <part element="tns:contact" name="parameters" />
    </message>

    <message name="contactResponse">
        <part element="tns:contactResponse" name="parameters" />
    </message>

    <message name="WhatizitException">
        <part element="tns:WhatizitException" name="fault" />
    </message>

    <message name="getPipelinesStatus">
        <part element="tns:getPipelinesStatus" name="parameters" />
    </message>

    <message name="getPipelinesStatusResponse">
        <part element="tns:getPipelinesStatusResponse" name="parameters" />
    </message>

    <message name="queryPmid">
        <part element="tns:queryPmid" name="parameters" />
    </message>

    <message name="queryPmidResponse">
        <part element="tns:queryPmidResponse" name="parameters" />
    </message>

    <message name="search">
        <part element="tns:search" name="parameters" />
    </message>

    <message name="searchResponse">
        <part element="tns:searchResponse" name="parameters" />
    </message>


    <portType name="whatizit">
        <operation name="contact">
            <input message="tns:contact" />
            <output message="tns:contactResponse" />
            <fault message="tns:WhatizitException" name="WhatizitException" />
        </operation>
        <operation name="getPipelinesStatus">
            <input message="tns:getPipelinesStatus" />
            <output message="tns:getPipelinesStatusResponse" />
            <fault message="tns:WhatizitException" name="WhatizitException" />
        </operation>
        <operation name="queryPmid">
            <input message="tns:queryPmid" />
            <output message="tns:queryPmidResponse" />
            <fault message="tns:WhatizitException" name="WhatizitException" />
        </operation>
        <operation name="search">
            <input message="tns:search" />
            <output message="tns:searchResponse" />
            <fault message="tns:WhatizitException" name="WhatizitException" />
        </operation>
    </portType>

    <binding type="tns:whatizit" name="pipelineBinding">
        <soap:binding style="document"
            transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
        <operation name="contact">
            <soap:operation soapAction="" />
            <input>
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </output>
            <fault name="WhatizitException">
                <soap:fault use="literal" name="WhatizitException" />
            </fault>
        </operation>
        <operation name="getPipelinesStatus">
            <soap:operation soapAction="" />
            <input>
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </output>
            <fault name="WhatizitException">
                <soap:fault use="literal" name="WhatizitException" />
            </fault>
        </operation>
        <operation name="queryPmid">
            <soap:operation soapAction="" />
            <input>
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </output>
            <fault name="WhatizitException">
                <soap:fault use="literal" name="WhatizitException" />
            </fault>
        </operation>
        <operation name="search">
            <soap:operation soapAction="" />
            <input>
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </input>
            <output>
                <mime:multipartRelated>
                    <mime:part>
                        <soap:body parts="" use="literal" />
                    </mime:part>
                    <mime:part>
                        <mime:content part="parameters" type="text/xml" />
                    </mime:part>
                </mime:multipartRelated>
            </output>
            <fault name="WhatizitException">
                <soap:fault use="literal" name="WhatizitException" />
            </fault>
        </operation>
    </binding>
    <service name="whatizit">
        <port binding="tns:pipelineBinding" name="pipeline">
            <!--<soap:address location="http://www.ebi.ac.uk/webservices/whatizit/ws"/> -->
            <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/whatizit/ws" />
        </port>
    </service>
</definitions>
```

Now I am very new to web services using WSDL. I'm experiencing two errors that at this line that I cannot fix:

```
<output>
                <mime:multipartRelated>
                    <mime:part>
                        <soap:body parts="" use="literal" />
                    </mime:part>
                    <mime:part>
                        <mime:content part="parameters" type="text/xml" />
                    </mime:part>
                </mime:multipartRelated>
            </output>
```

Multiple annotations found at this line:

```
- cvc-attribute.3: The value '' of attribute 'parts' on element 'soap:body' is not valid with respect to its type, 
     'NMTOKENS'.
    - cvc-minLength-valid: Value '' with length = '0' is not facet-valid with respect to minLength '1' for type 
     'NMTOKENS'.
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I will have a look a little later but this WSDL is not WSI compliant which will explain why it is so difficult to use. I have imported it into SOAP UI and will try to get to it shortly but it is violating BP2703 of WSI compliance.

Comment: Thanks. I managed to solve the issue as follows: <output>
                <mime:multipartRelated>
                    <mime:part>
                        <soap:body parts="nmtokens" use="literal" />
                    </mime:part>
                    <mime:part>
                        <mime:content part="parameters" type="text/xml" />
                    </mime:part>
                </mime:multipartRelated>
            </output> 

Basically, Eclipse was asking the parts filed to be of type nmtokens.

Comment: Martin add it as an answer and accept your own answer. It might help someone else.

Comment: @Namphibian Yes, I did. But I cannot accept my own answer -:)

Comment: You can just wait 24 hours or so.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I managed to solve the issue. Basically, Eclipse was asking the parts filed to be of type nmtokens. So I changed the block from:

```
<output>
            <mime:multipartRelated>
                <mime:part>
                    <soap:body parts="" use="literal" />
                </mime:part>
                <mime:part>
                    <mime:content part="parameters" type="text/xml" />
                </mime:part>
            </mime:multipartRelated>
        </output>
```

to

```
 <output>
                <mime:multipartRelated>
                    <mime:part>
                        <soap:body parts="nmtokens" use="literal" />
                    </mime:part>
                    <mime:part>
                        <mime:content part="parameters" type="text/xml" />
                    </mime:part>
                </mime:multipartRelated>
            </output>
```

And the error disappears.